# How to reduce Energy Impact in this Streaming Code

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

Hello Guys I am developing a live streaming radio app. Everything is fine but I noticed that, the Energy Impact is very high. When I try to upload this app apple will reject or not? I use background modes for playing songs in background

## ViewController

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer(url: STREAMING_URL! as URL)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("AVAudioSession is Active")
            } catch {
                print("Active error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Category error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    //Play
    @IBAction func playBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        player.play()
    }

    //Pause
    @IBAction func pauseBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        player.pause()
    }
```

## Energy Impact

[image]

How to reduce this energy Impact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple will not reject it. AVPlayer is managing buffering and cache to reuse your stream data.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I made few audio books apps in past. But we are handling buffer time and also handling network drop situations. So Do that few necessary things,Apple will not reject it after that.